# Can't read anything after sending EOF?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, eof, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = getchar(); //EOF (ctrl + d )
    while( ( c = getchar() ) != '?' )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", c == EOF );//infinite loop printing 1
    }
}
```

**What happens here?**

It is as if EOF completely blocks reading anything after it?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of EOF, to signal the stream to stop reading. E.g. when all content from a file has been read (hence EOF = end of file) the stream should stop reading.

Comment: EOF is short for "end of file". Did you know that? I assume you do. So please explain what you expect to read from a file after you arrived at the end of the file or what other  special aspects put your situation apart.

Comment: regarding:  `char c = getchar();`   the function: `getchar()` actually returns an `int`.  and, depending on your implementation of `char` (signed or unsigned)` it might not be able to recognize EOF`.  So, start by `int c = getchar();`

Answer (score 7):

You need to call [clearerr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clearerr) on `stdin` to clear the EOF. Also, note that `getchar` returns an `int` and not a `char` because `EOF` does not fit in a char.